# Why is my React Code not showing in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting out with React and I'm having some trouble displaying the code in the browser. I followed a tutorial using a sandbox system and everything worked just fine. Trying the same in my IDE in a pre-existing project didn't work out.

I want to display a simple heading. This is my JS code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Heading</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and this is my HMTL:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>REACT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the heading isn't displayed in the browser. The stylesheet works just fine. Dependencies are added properly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you have root in js but testroot in html?

Comment: Your `<div id="testroot"></div>` should be `<div id="root"></div>` or you have to change `document.getElementById("root")` to `document.getElementById("testroot")`

Comment: No, sorry, edited it wrong when I posted this question. They were called testroot in both files.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the wrong id. You should change `root` to `testroot` or vice-versa. This should work fine if you have correctly set up the babel config.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Heading</h1>,
    document.getElementById("testroot")
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to rename both mentions of root/testroot when editing this question. They of course have the same name in my project, but the heading still isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have written code using ES6 modules with Node.js module resolution. It won't run in a browser.

You need to convert it to browser-compatible JavaScript using Babel and Webpack as described [in the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment). (Make sure you click the "Optional: Instructions for following along locally using your preferred text editor" text).

The sandbox you were using did all that set up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare React CDN link and babel link to be shown on the screen. Look for it on google.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).